# lstate error: no such file or directory while building Docker from a custom image with Docker build command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I have create a custom image for lamp stack with following files

```
apps.conf 
Dockerfile 
entrypoint.sh 
start.sh 
supervisord.conf
```

`Dockerfile` was create with ENV, RUN, ADD and CMD command.

Each application installed successfully, but stuck it at ADD command and check the given path which is correct.

```
ADD /home/ktpl/nayan/MyLamp/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

ADD /home/ktpl/nayan/MyLamp/apps.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apps.conf

ADD /home/ktpl/nayan/MyLamp/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ADD /home/ktpl/nayan/MyLamp/start.sh /start.sh
```

[image]

Process is stuck at Add command.:

```
lstat home/ktpl/nayan/lamp/supervisord.conf: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker builds always work relative to the context - i.e. the directory you pass in the `docker build` command. [You cannot use absolute paths in ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), you should be specifying the source file relative to the build context.

For local files you should use [COPY instead of ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/add-or-copy) too, so your Dockerfile becomes:

```
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
#etc.
```

And then you build it from your MyLamp directory with `docker build -t my-tag .`

Answer (score 0):

`ADD` can be used to copy local files to image while building.

Couple of things:

- You are building an image using current directory
- In your case, `/home/ktpl/nayan/lamp` is the valid directory
- Not sure if you have a directory `/home/ktpl/nayan/MyLamp` exists and files present in there.

As per the [documentation of docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

If your files are in the same directory as you build image, then you may use below statements in `Dockerfile`

```
ADD ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

ADD ./apps.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/apps.conf

ADD ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ADD ./start.sh /start.sh
```

Of course, like it was mentioned in the other answer, `COPY` can also be used.

Sample `Dockerfile` contents:

```
FROM busybox
ADD ./test.txt /test.txt
CMD ls /
```

You can building image and running it shows file being added in the below image.

[image]

If all the files and directories present and still you see this problem, then check `.dockerignore` has entry for the same.

Comment: Thanks for point out my error and details. got the idea about my docker file error point and thanks for sharing such important areas where i need to focus while making docker file.

Comment: @NayanVanza, glad to know that this is helpful.